# Reading a file larger than 2GB into memory in Java

Tags: java, io

Since `ByteArrayInputStream` is limited to 2GB, is there any alternate solution that allows me to store the whole contents of a 2.3GB (and possibly larger) file into an `InputStream` to be read by Stax2?

Current code:

```
            XMLInputFactory xmlInputFactory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
            XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(in); //ByteArrayInputStream????
            try
            {
                SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");

                Schema schema = factory.newSchema(new StreamSource(schemaInputStream));
                Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
                validator.validate(new StAXSource(xmlStreamReader));

            }

            finally
            {
                xmlStreamReader.close();
            }
```

For performance tuning, variable `in` must not come from disk. I have **plenties** of RAM.

Comment: In .net, the same problem exists, and there's several solution. Look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx)

Comment: Maybe splitting over several includes (several files) is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NIO to read the file into a gigantic ByteBuffer, and then create a stream class that reads the ByteBuffer. There are several such floating around in open sources.

Answer (score 5):

The whole point of StAX2 is that you do not need to read the file in to memory. You can just supply the source, and let the StAX StreamReader pull the data as it needs to.

What additional constraints do you have that you are not showing in your question?

If you have lots of memory, and you want to get good performance, just wrap your InputStream with a large byte buffer, and let the buffer do the buffering for you:

```
// 4 meg buffer on the stream
InputStream buffered = new BufferedInputStream(schemaInputStream, 1024 * 1024 * 4);
```

An alternative to solving this in Java is to create a RAMDisk, and to store the file on that, which would remove the problem from Java, where your basic limitation is that you can only have just less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` values in a single array.

Comment: I't s a performance test where I need to find the bottleneck. I have been **explicitly** requested to do this test: load the whole file into memory, validate it and supply timing to my boss.

Comment: Edited my answer to add the BufferedInputStream concept. As for your boss's requirement, there is no way to create a simple in-memory segment of more than 2Gig values (bytes), so you need to do some sort of hackery (like multiple arrays of bytes, or bitwise shifting, or memory windows, or something) to get there, which introduces other performance constraints anyway. Your best bet is to create RAMDisk, and load the file on to that, and take the problem out of Java.

Comment: Yes, I was about to suggest ram disk. Does that count? It's all in memory, certainly, though not all in the JVM's memory.

Comment: Production code currently uses PipedStreams to perform validation *while* the file is generated, and with TeeInputStream the output is also sent to a compression layer. This has great performance when validation is not enabled.

Comment: I'll take ramdisk into consideration, +1 @chiastic-security

Comment: Have you thought about coding up your own `InputStream` that stores and uses two `ByteArray`s? This should work, provided that `InputStream` isn't inherently limited, e.g. using an `int` for its position in the stream.

Comment: I have done that multiple times, but bottom line is that, if you are going for raw performance, you will be better off using a Memory Mapped ByteBuffer, and that is not compatible with the StAX API, and you will need to do memory copies anyway. At that point your limiting factor will be the parsing of the data, not the performance of the source. I suspect a BufferedInputStream with a big enough buffer will be more than you need.

Comment: @rolfl I completely agree, but I'm trying to find a way to keep OP's boss happy :) This seems the best way of getting the whole thing into JVM memory before starting.

Answer (score 0):

If you have huge quantities of memory, you really won't get any performance improvement anyway. It's only getting read in once either way, and the disk cache will ensure it gets done optimally. Just use a disk-based input stream.

Answer (score -1):

You can use memory writing the data compressed to a

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream
... new GZIPOutputStream(baos));

byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray(); // < 100 MB?

ByteArrayInputStream ....
```

And then later wrap the input stream in a GZIPInputStream.

Still a minor slow down, but should be ideal for XML.

Comment: Good workaround for overcoming memory occupation. Especially with XML, a 2.3GB file is deflated to 70MB. I should accept this answer because it's the perfect response given the scope of the question. However, the question is not well formed (X-Y problem): I need to perform an XML validation benchmark, for which compression overhead is not the greatest idea. Thus, yours cannot be a general solution because one might have so huge plenties of data that it goes beyond 2GB when compressed, but that may lead to a different world of Q&As

Comment: Fine, thanks for still trying (2.3 GB -> 70 MB). I'll leave the answer for other with similar questions, as gzip is often overlooked. Like using a RAM disk / SSD too.

Comment: Actually, my business case (ECB ABS reporting) requires GZIP compression of the produced XML on disk, so I didn't have to try your code, I already got the answer ;-)